# AS3 accessing other domains

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, cross-domain

I have a AS3 swf that scrapes google images for a search query and displays some of the results. It works locally, but when the swf is on a server it can't access google. I've tried Security.allowDomain, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Google's [crossdomain.xml](http://www.google.com/crossdomain.xml) might be [preventing you](http://www.flashperfection.com/tutorials/Flash-Cross-Domain-Access-85118.html) from accessing it. Try their [Ajax Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/) together with [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#includeExamplesSummary) instead. Even then, you can't access the images in search results if third party sites doesn't have a crossdomain policy file that allows your domain to access files from there.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to use a server script to retrieve the requests (i.e. loadImage.php?url=http://....) but its very demanding for the server (as it has to download the files and then send them to the client)... depending on your needs some cache system could help...